# C++ Dynamic binding in method argument

Tags: c++, rtti, dynamic-binding

I recently wanted to get c++ to dynamically resolve a member/function by its input parameter which comes in some derived versions. Here is what I mean:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
};

class DerivedA : public Base {
};

class DerivedB : public Base {
};

class DerivedC : public Base {
};

class Test {
public:
    void world( DerivedA *instance )
    {
        std::cout << "DerivedA" << std::endl;
    }

    void world( DerivedB *instance )
    {
        std::cout << "DerivedB" << std::endl;
    }

    void world( Base *instance )
    {
        std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base *a = new Base;
    Base *b = new DerivedA;
    Base *c = new DerivedB;
    Base *d = new DerivedC;

    Test hello;
    hello.world( a );
    hello.world( b );
    hello.world( c );
    hello.world( d );

    return 0;
}
```

The behaviour I **WANTED** is this:

```
Base
DerivedA
DerivedB
Base
```

But for sure the output I am **REALLY** getting is this:

```
Base
Base
Base
Base
```

I understand, that dynamic binding is the other way, resolving the correct member function within the derived classes of base and not like that way - but can it work in any way for that?

Maybe I am only missing the essential point..

However, many thanks in advance!

Sebastian

Comment: What is the use case here? I don't see why you can't simply define each variable as the corresponding derived type instead of `Base`. The only way to get the functionality you want would be to use `dynamic_cast<>`.

Comment: You're passing `Base*` to all of those functions. You need to use [virtual functions](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/122-virtual-functions/) for what you want to achieve (You would have to make the `world` function a member-function).

Comment: @RedAlert: You would also need to then have at least one virtual member function, and do `if(dynamic_cast<X>(instance) { ... }` - both of which are probably more time-consuming than calling a virtual function in the first place.

Comment: First, the sense behind this is, that the instances are created in other functions, but at the place were I want to run different code from the "Test"-Class, I cannot determine which class each object is an instance of. I know, that I could do it like Mats Petersson said, but I wanted to keep the code in the Test-Class, not in the Objects.

Comment: Then you probably need to find a different scheme for your whole test strategy. Let me have a think...

Comment: You might be correct with this. But what can I use here if I want to keep the code separated from the Derived classes?

Comment: One solution, that I can think of right now (I may be able to come up with something else in a few hours or days time), is to add a wrapper-class. Let me write that up...

Comment: Ok, I have added a wrapper type solution to my answer. I'm not convinced that is the BEST way to solve the problem, but it may be ONE way - part of it really depends on what you are going to do, how many tests you have, etc, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are all `Base*`. The compiler does not track "what the variable contains". If that is what you want to do then you need to use a virtual function in the class that you derive from, for example:

```
class Base {
 public: 
   virtual const char* MyName() { return "Base"; }
};

class DerivedA : public Base {
 public: 
   virtual const char* MyName() { return "DerivedA"; }
};
... similiar for all derived classes ... 

void world( Base *instance )
{
    std::cout << instance->MyName() << std::endl;
}
```

(Edit: To get exactly the behaviour you list in the first case, you'd need to NOT implement the MyName() function in the DerivedC class)

So, using a wrapper class may be the solution for a test-setup. Here's something I just hacked up, without much consideration and sophistication:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
};

class DerivedA : public Base {
};

class DerivedB : public Base {
};

class DerivedC : public Base {
};

class Test {
public:
    void world( DerivedA *instance )
    {
        std::cout << "DerivedA" << std::endl;
    }

    void world( DerivedB *instance )
    {
        std::cout << "DerivedB" << std::endl;
    }

    void world( Base *instance )
    {
        std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Wrapper
{
public:
    Wrapper(T* i) : instance(i)
    {
    }
    ~Wrapper()
    {
        delete instance;
    }

    void doTest(Test& t)
    {
        t.world(instance);
    }

    T* instance;
};


int main()
{
    Test hello;
    Wrapper<Base> a(new Base);
    Wrapper<DerivedA> b(new DerivedA);
    Wrapper<DerivedB> c(new DerivedB);
    Wrapper<DerivedC> d(new DerivedC);

    a.doTest(hello);
    b.doTest(hello);
    c.doTest(hello);
    d.doTest(hello);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C++, you can't do that (well, at least not without using `if(dynamic_cast<...>(...)) { ... }` type constructs, and that's REALLY not the right way to go).

Comment: Simply great the approach with the wrapper. Also shows the limits of c++ ;) Not sure if I am using it or accepting it as an hint for using a more proper OO design :) - Thanks!

Comment: There are quite possibly prettier/better solutions... But none that I can think of at half past 11 at night whilst trying to get a visitor pattern to work on my AST in my compiler... ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your example you don't have a runtime polymorphism scheme (i.e., dynamic binding). What you have is an overloaded member function and in overload resolution the compiler correctly selects `void world( Base *instance )`.

In order to get what you want you should apply an inheritance scheme like the one below:

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual ~Base() {}
  virtual void world() const { std::cout << "Base" << std::endl; }
};

class DerivedA : public Base {
public:
  virtual ~DerivedA() {}
  void world() const { std::cout << "DerivedA" << std::endl; }
};

class DerivedB : public Base {
public:
  virtual ~DerivedB() {}
  void world() const  { std::cout << "DerivedB" << std::endl; }
};

class DerivedC : public Base {
public:
  virtual ~DerivedC() {}
  using Base::world;
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c01dd9402a5701f)

**Edit:**

In order to keep your code as intented in one place you could add to the above scheme the following altered version of the `Test` class:

```
class Test {
public:
  void world( DerivedA *instance ) { instance->world(); }
  void world( DerivedB *instance ) { instance->world(); }
  void world( Base     *instance ) { instance->world(); }
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e612f5422449fda)

Unfortunately, overload resolution takes place at compile time whereas dynamic-dispatching takes place at run-time. Thus, if you intended for the compiler to deduce the underlying type from a `Base` pointer and then pick-up the right member function from `Test` class, this is not feasible.

Comment: thanks, but as I commented on Mats Peterssons solution, I wanted to keep the code inside the "Test"-Class.